# jQuery Validate treats errors as separate instances instead of combining them

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, error-handling, jquery-validate

I am able to relocate my jquery validate errors to specific container set above my form but the elements show up as separate errors (multiple).

Ideally, I want to have one large error box (which on my other pages I already call with class 'error') and state something a long the lines of "Please fix the following errors:..."
with the results being an unordered list.

My jquery is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {     
    $("#login_form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#containererreurtotal",
        wrapper: "li",
        errorClass: "error",
        rules: {
            AGTNO: 'required',
            AGTPW: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            AGTNO: 'Your Number or Email Address is required.',
            AGTPW: 'Your Password is required.'
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
            $('#overlay').show();
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Above my form, I have the following:

```
<ul id="containererreurtotal"></ul>
```

any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with the problem you're experiencing, there isn't enough info for me to recreate it myself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HK4TP/ is my interpretation, it's working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HK4TP/1/

Hide your error container and give it the appropriate styling, the rest will be handled by the plugin.

Comment: It is conflicting with my existing .error class and this was the problem. I appreciate your help, I was ultimate facing the issue of styling individual errors as opposed to styling my entire div container. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could be a bystander to your success =]